# How to give gradient to TextView in android?

Tags: android

i search from while for giving gradient to textView in android.but not getting proper solution any where.

i have the screen like this[image: the text in the image is actually having the gradient]

if i put the images as text, but i have many textview which having gradient,then application may be large in size.
so if anybody know the solution please post it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here It goes,

```
int[] color = {Color.DKGRAY,Color.CYAN};
        float[] position = {0, 1};
        TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.REPEAT;
        LinearGradient lin_grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 35,color,position, tile_mode);
        Shader shader_gradient = lin_grad;
        your_text_view.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient);
```

Edited:

Hi @android developer,

If you want to do some vertical or any gradients to the view,

Please use,

`RadialGradient` instead of `LinearGradient.`

Only thing is you have to adjust,

```
x coordinate of the center of the radius.
y coordinate of the center of the radius.

and also,

radius value of the view.
```

and use Tile Mode as Mirror instead of Repeat.

I have sample but it may not exact of what you want,

```
TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.MIRROR or TileMode.REPEAT;
        RadialGradient rad_grad = new RadialGradient(0, 3, 5, Color.BLUE,Color.RED,tile_mode, tile_mode);
        Shader shader_gradient = rad_grad;
        your_text_view.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient);
```

And you can use `SweepGradient` also instead of `LinearGradient`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response,But when i set this gradient to background

Comment: When in the sense?... In the xml layout file, set as a android:background for the textview.

Comment: sorry for half commment,But when i set this gradient to background it is applied to background not to textview color.

Comment: okay. take a look at this, file:///Users/b2information/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-26%20at%205.51.37%20PM.png

Comment: What is it                   

file:///Users/b2information/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-26%20at%205.51.37%20‌​PM.png

Comment: Then wt is there, you have to give the same color , which is given to the background also. i guess it was black ... Then it should be look like wt you expected...

Comment: No no i want the text color to be gradient not text background and the text color is white not black.my background is already black. and that gradient is set to textview background no to text view color.

Comment: Please see the updated answer above, this might helps. I mistakenly given you the gradient for background...

Comment: Thank you very much.this what i exactly want.Thanks again..!

Comment: Okay. sorry for the late and actually I dont'n know about tick.
Now i know it. Thanks...!

Comment: Hi, @TrackRuler, could you please clarify if there is any way to do this from xml? So that to reuse some style for text for different TextViews without setting this gradient programmatically for each separate TextView?

Comment: @TrackRuler Is this vertical or horizontal gradient? How can I change to the other types of gradients? Also, for some reason it didn't work for me in the case of using 5 colors and positions.

Comment: @TrackRuler Is there a way to set more than 2 colors for a gradient, yet use it for horizontal/vertical gradient (not around a position like a circle )?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can give array of colors to your LinearGradient,
int[] color = {Color.DKGRAY,Color.CYAN,Color.RED};

Comment: @TrackRuler I've already tried it (together with the positions of course) but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @TrackRuler I've tried again, and it seems the y1 argument for the LinearGradient is incorrect. I think it should be set as the height of the textView